# how to run memcached on UDP ports only

Tags: centos, udp

How can i configure memcached to run on udp ports only on centos box ? Right now it is listening on TCP ports by default. Here is my memcached configuration file.

```
cat /etc/sysconfig/memcached
PORT="11212"
USER="memcached"
MAXCONN="1000000"
CACHESIZE="64"
OPTIONS="-v -r"
```

Comment: why do you want it on UDP, it performs poorly on UDP...

Comment: We are testing something,can please give guidelines of how to run it only on UDP ports?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to edit the memcached configuration file and change the OPTIONS section. On the CentOS 6 system I have to hand memcached is listening on UDP and TCP port 11211. To disable TCP and continue to allow UDP I had to do the following

```
OPTIONS='-p 0 -U 11211'
```

the `-p 0` disables listening on TCP and `-U 11222` enabled UDP/11211.

```
netstat -tunlp | grep memcached
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:11211           0.0.0.0:*          11159/memcached     
udp        0      0 :::11211                :::*               11159/memcached
```

Comment: is the -p 0 documented somewhere? I could only find how to explicitly disable UDP by using -U 0, but for the -p argument there was no mention of 0 disabling it.

Comment: Not that I can see I tried it to see what would happen based on what the docs say about -U.

Answer (score 0):

OPTIONS="-U 22222" enables memcached on udp port 22222. just add it to the options you already have.

Comment: Do i need to add it to /etc/sysconfig/memcached file instead of PORT="11212" ? 
 what should be exact parameter value. Thanks for the help, highly apperciated.

Comment: Change your line
    OPTIONS="-v -r"
to
    OPTIONS="-v -r -U 22222"

It doesn't disable TCP completely though, I think that's not possible. But you don't need to use the TCP connection and use the UDP connection instead